# What is a concise, general method of property testing against nan values in F#?

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fscheck

I am doing some property testing in F# using FsCheck.  I therefore wish to guarantee that certain conditions always hold, regardless of input arguments.

Consider I define a trivial identity function for `float` values.

```
let floatId (x : float) = x
```

I then define a test of this function which I know should always hold:

```
let ``floatId returns input float`` x = floatId x = x
```

This is a trivial test, I am just checking that calling my float identity function returns the same as the input float.

I then plug this function into FsCheck:

```
Check.Quick ``floatId returns input float``
```

Unfortunately, this property test fails!

> ```
> Falsifiable, after 21 tests (0 shrinks) (StdGen (1872424299,296201373)):
> Original: 
> nan
> ```

Of course, looking back, it was pretty obvious this was going to happen, we know that `nan <> nan`.

Due to structural comparison in F#, this can plague (slightly) more complex test cases involving collections too.

If I design a similar function for float lists:

```
let listFloatId (lst : float list) = lst

let ``listFloatId returns input float list`` lst = listFloatId lst = lst
```

> ```
> Falsifiable, after 6 tests (3 shrinks) (StdGen (1874889363,296201373)):
> Original:
> [nan; 2.0; 2.25; 4.940656458e-324]
> Shrunk:
> [nan]
> ```

Same problem again!

---

Obviously I can engineer around this problem by creating my own equality testing functions, that's fine for `float` values but it becomes more complex to extend to collections like `list` since I have to start using `List.forall2` with my custom equality function and generally specialising my code to each individual collection type.

Is there a general way of solving this problem in F#?

Comment: I would probably solve this with a new operator which did a equality taking into account nan

Comment: @JohnPalmer I'm doing this to put one possible solution which doesn't appear to be well known on record.  Would definitely be interested to hear others.

Comment: Ah - didn't realise you already had an answer for this - it looks like that function is basically what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this problem using the [`LanguagePrimitives.GenericEqualityER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/languageprimitives.genericequalityer%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) function.  This checks equality using Equivalance Relation semantics.  This function actually sites the specific example of comparing `[nan]` lists.

Test cases can be defined like this:

```
let ``ER : floatId returns input float`` x = LanguagePrimitives.GenericEqualityER (floatId x)  x

let ``ER : listFloatId returns input float list`` lst = LanguagePrimitives.GenericEqualityER (listFloatId lst)  lst
```

This time:

> ```
> Ok, passed 100 tests.
> Ok, passed 100 tests.
> ```

(I am asking, and answering, this question because the above property was raised in the FSharp Software Foundation Slack channel and I thought it would be useful to have this solution on record.  I can find almost no mention of this function online beyond the documentation on the `LanguagePrimitives` module).